# MySQL/C# Stored Procedure Not Returning Value

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have been having difficulty returning a value to a C# application from a Stored Procedure. The Procedure is returning a value in MySql workbench but not C#. In the C# Output there is no value being displayed. The following Procedure and method i call are included below:

```
            /*
            CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_FindChildID` (OUT CID VARCHAR(6))  
            BEGIN  

                SELECT MAX(ChildID) INTO @CID FROM Child;
                SET @CID = SUBSTRING(@CID FROM 1); 
                SELECT @CID;
            END //
            */

            public bool callProcedure()
            {
                if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                {
                    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.CommandText = "proc_FindChildID";

                        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CID", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 6));
                        command.Parameters["@CID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        string t_return = command.Parameters["@CID"].Value.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("ID:" + t_return);

                    this.CloseConnection();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know MySqlCommand but normally if it was MSSQL i would have called `object o = command.ExecuteScalar();` instead of `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` to get the value.